# How to create a break in function with no return value printed on console?

Tags: r, function, return-value

I am aware of the `invisible()` function but it does not seem to work when one wants to break inside function:

```
bar <- function() {
   if (file.exists("data/some.rds") | (1 + 1 == 2)) return()
   "something else"
}
foo <- function() {
   if (file.exists("data/some.rds") | (1 + 1 == 2)) invisible()
   "something else"
}
bar()
> NULL
foo()
> [1] "something else"
```

---

NB: `(1 + 1 == 2)` evaluates to TRUE and is used here to make a reproductible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `invisible()` modifies the attributes of an object. If you want to leave the function early, you still need to explicitly return. This put the invisible inside the return.

```
foo <- function() {
  if (file.exists("data/some.rds") | (1 + 1 == 2)) return(invisible())
  "something else"
}
```